# Custom Segue in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using Push to navigate to different pages. As you know it always moves right to left. I want it to work like this:

1 - when I click on a button in the left side of the current page, it comes left to right.

2 - when I click on a button in the right side of the current page, it comes right to left.

3 - When I click on the button which loads current page, it comes down to Up. (like Modal)

This is what I tried by implementing `UIStoryboardSegue` and create custom Segue:

```
- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    [src.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

or:

```
- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController popToViewController:[src.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];;
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
}
```

But they are not working in a way that I want.
I want them to work like Push Segue (I want the viewDidLoad, ... is called again)
Can you give me some help? (Please share some codes in your answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I need to do:

```
-(void)perform {  
   UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
   UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];                    

   CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
   transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
   transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
   transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; 
   [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
   [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];    
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`IIViewDeckController` is something like which you want..

see this demo..

[IIViewDeckController Open Source](http://mattters.com/iphone-development/videos/open-source-iphone-component-for-elegant-sliding-views-inspired-by-pat)

[IIViewDeck from scoop.it](http://www.scoop.it/t/dev-various/p/2320132348/iiviewdeckcontroller)

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I want. I want to handle it using Custom seque, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: yes mate, just download the demo and see the logic only you wil get idea from this demo just action with your button and also here swipe gesture available for move one to another view..